# I can't see a php include page

Tags: php, wampserver

I have an included php page into index.html.

```
<?php include "inc/header.php";?>
```

Dreamveawer cs5 is configured for viewing via wamp server.
On f12 I can't see this included file (only index.html is viewed, without includes)
If I open header.php itself - f12 - works well.
What could be the reason, please.

Comment: is your server setup to execute php within html files?

Comment: If you include it in your `index.html` it won't be interpreted as PHP. Try to rename the `index.html` into `index.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index.html` is an HTML file, so PHP won't be parsed. Name the file `index.php` instead.

Comment: `.html` files aren't necessarily "non-PHP" or "non-parsable". Renaming of course is the easiest method, but the real underlying problem is that `.html` are not configured to be parsed by PHP by default.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the file cannot be located. I suspect if you change `include` to `require`, you will see a relevant error message. You need to either change the path you are trying to include, or change your include_path variable:

```
set_include_path("/path/to/your/lib/" . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . get_include_path());
```

**edit** As commenters noted elsewhere, this only applies if your main file *is* being interpreted through PHP.